# DDD, BoundedContexts, Domain Events and Transactions

Tags: domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

I am currently in the process of creating a Proof of Concept for a product/party administration system, based on the principles of DDD. One of the requirements is that the party data (customer, reseller) will be stored in a CRM on the web and the product specific data will be stored in a SQL database on premise (see below).

**CRM System (Web Based)**
Customer (contains name, address, email, contact preference etc)
Reseller (contains name, address, active status)

**Product System (On Premise)**
BaseProduct (defines a vanilla product)
ResellerProduct (defines a customisation of a base product which will be sold by the reseller)
CustomerProduct (defines a product which the customer as registered).

I have been conducting a lot of research into the different approaches of how I could implement the solution, but am struggling to make sense of all the concepts and how they apply to my problem.

I started out by splitting the areas into 2 different bounded contexts, Party and Product. I defined domain models for each of these contexts, and where entities referenced concepts in the other model I left these as simple Guid Ids (i.e. CustomerProduct in the product domain would have a CustomerRef value of the related Guid).

I then implemented a Party infrastructure implementation which used API calls to the web CRM and a Product infrastructure implementation which used NHibernate. For each of these I implemented a UnitOfWork so I could control the transaction process in each context. The application layer would have the two contexts injected at runtime and use them.

For Example:

- ApplicationService.RegisterNewProduct(customerId,
  ProductId)
- Start the transaction of each unit of
  work (PartyUnitOfWork.Begin(),
  ProductUnitOfWork.Begin())
- Use the repositories for each context
  to find the relevant domain objects
  (Party.Customer.Find(Id),
  Product.ResellerProduct.Find(Id))
- Perform logic to determine if
  customer is eligible, product is
  valid etc.
- Create a new CustomerProduct and save
  to the product System
- Commit each contexts UnitOfWork

I then started to explore bounded contexts a bit further and was thinking about refactoring the app so that each context had a limited representation of concepts from the other, but only specific to that context. i.e. In the Product context I would have a customer entity, which had an Id, Name and active status but maybe not contact preferences etc. I would then use DomainEvents to coordinate activities between the different systems to keep their data up to date (i.e. If a new customer was created in the CRM system an event would be raised and handled by the Product system to update its representation of customer). Therefore the above example would change so only the Product context was used.

To confuse matters further, say the ‘RegisterNewProduct’ call also created a new Customer, would I created the customer in the Product system and raise a ‘NewCustomer’ event which would be handled by the Party system?

I would be interested to gather peoples comments on these ideas?

Comment: Why do you need two concepts? Are there any terms that have different meanings in these contexts? If there is no ambiguity, I would start with a simple context and then split it if it's size make in unmanageable.

Comment: Ideally I would only want one context i.e. a Customer with a collection of CustomerProducts. However because the Customer and the CustomerProduct in this case would be in separate systems I thought they would need to be separated. Therefore I would then have a persistence layer to interact with the CRM entities and another to interact with the database entities. I am unsure how I would structure it otherwise; would I have a persistence layer which could handle access to both the CRM and the database via NHibernate?

Comment: I think that how you store and retrive your data is a technical detail, and you should bury this logic deep inside Repositories implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides my comment/question, there is fundamental issue with UnitOfWork approach you described. You'll run into a whole class of problems with one of the units committed and one failed. You will end up with a distributed transaction spanning two context.

A better (subjectively) approach to bounded contexts, if you really need to have more than one, is to have asynchronous, message based communication between them. You execute a command against an aggregate in one context and in the same transaction as persisting the changes to the DB, you publish (for example via NServiceBus or MassTransit) a message (an event) that something happened. The other context receives the message/event and reacts.

If you are a purist, you could use this approach to all inter-aggregate communication. By doing this you could remove the requirement of having a Unit of Work at all.

Does it make any sense?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I agree with the UnitOfWork problems you detailed, and this is what lead me to thinking of using bounded contexts so each context would only be interacting with one datastore. In regards to the structure of application with events, would I need to represent data from one system in and raise events i.e. In the product system (database backed) I have a concept of a customer, which is an aggregate root on which I call customer.assignToProduct(product), this would then raise an event which could be handled by the CRM system and update its customer/product representation?

Comment: Is customer-product relationship stored in both systems? Who owns this relationship?

Comment: Ideally if it was one system I would have customer as the aggregate root and it would own the relationship to customer product. However because customer will be in the CRM in the cloud and the CustomerProduct in the on premise database the relationship is split between the two and I will end up with a Customer aggregate root for the CRM and a CustomerProduct root for the on- premise system. What I'm wondering is if I should create the concept of a Customer in the onpremise system to reflect the relationship better?

Comment: ... And create the concept of CustomerProduct in the CRM and then keep each root updated using events?

Comment: I would create CustomerProcuct in CRM and Customer in product management app. In the system that is responsible for managing the relationship I would add a method to proper aggregate to create the relationship. After creating I would publish an event so that the other system can synchronize its view of data.

Comment: Thanks Szymon, that’s validated my thinking on the matter. I think I was getting too hung up on separating the domain by persistence storage rather than by functional area. I now see that I should be thinking in terms of different contexts, with the CRM functionality as one context (which is responsible for managing the client data, and showing a read-only view of the products customers have) and the product system (which is responsible for adding products to customers, but not for editing customers).